# Pandas - Key Error when key clearly exists in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function I'm trying to apply to a dataframe 'players'.

'players' is taken from a larger dataframe 'df_tot' using .groupby():

```
players = df_tot.groupby(["Player", "Year"]).get_group(("Derrick White", 2022))
```

players returns the following dataframe:

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Rk | Player | Pos | Age | Tm | G | GS | MP | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17263 | 776 | 578 | Derrick White | SG | 27 | TOT | 75 | 52 | 2199 | 2022 |
| 17264 | 777 | 578 | Derrick White | SG | 27 | SAS | 49 | 48 | 1486 | 2022 |
| 17265 | 778 | 578 | Derrick White | SG | 27 | BOS | 26 | 4 | 713 | 2022 |

I want to return the row where 'Tm' = 'TOT'.

Here is the function I'm trying to apply to 'players':

```
def clean_traded(df):
    if df.shape[0]==1:
        return df
    else:
        row = df[df["Tm"]=="TOT"]
        row["Tm"] = df.iloc[-1,:]["Tm"]
        return row

players.apply(clean_traded)
```

However, I recieve:

```
 KeyError: 'Tm'
```

How is this possible when 'Tm' is clearly a column in 'players' dataframe? For example the below code:

```
print(players.columns.tolist())
```

Returns:

```
['Unnamed: 0', 'Rk', 'Player', 'Pos', 'Age', 'Tm', 'G', 'GS', 'MP', 'Year']
```

Any ideas? The below code doesn't produce an error, but I want to know why adding a "get_group" produces an error.

```
players = df_tot.groupby(["Player", "Year"]).apply(clean_traded)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're goal is, is there a reason you write this function and apply it instead of just filter the row with your condition like this:

```
res = players.loc[players['Tm']=='TOT',:]

print(res)
       Unnamed: 0   Rk         Player Pos  Age   Tm   G  GS    MP  Year
17263         776  578  Derrick White  SG   27  TOT  75  52  2199  2022
```

If you want to debug your function or get a better understanding of what is happening there, just put some print statements in it. For example `print(players)` at the beginning of your `else` statement. Then you will see why you get a `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to filter for ```players['TM'] == 'TOT'``` for every group created by the ```players = df_tot.groupby(["Player", "Year"])``` where there is more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not apply to your situation, but I have been fooled by trailing spaces in the column names in the past.

calling `df.columns` will list the column names with quotation marks, so that you can see an invisible leading or trailing space character if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` by default is applied to columns. And when it is applied, the columns are turned into Series. So when you do `players.apply(clean_traded)`, it first looks at `Unnamed: 0`, turns that into a Series, and then tries to apply `clean_traded` to that. This Series has the row names as labels, but the column name `'Unnamed: 0'` is not part of the Series. So this returns an error, because there is no `Tm` column in the Series.

You should just do `clean_traded(players)`. And there's almost certainly a simpler way of doing what you're traying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense now why there's a Key Error. I found a solution to what I'm attempting to do, but as a relatively new programmer I wanted to understand what's occurring behind the scenes with the ```apply``` function.